# Strange binary symbol using cygwin

Tags: cygwin

I have a problem that did not exist before.
when I execute a command like the one below,

```
ls | awk -F '_' '{print $1,$2}'
```

I get a strange output
 (seen through vim)

> ^[[0m^[[00;38;5;244m^[[m^[[00;38;5;136m<filename_prefix>
>   <filename_suffix>^[[0m

(seen through notepad++)

> [0m[00;38;5;244m[m[00;38;5;136m [0m

[image: notepad++ screenshot]

I am using: CYGWIN_NT-6.1 43-04772 2.4.1(0.293/5/3) 2016-01-24 11:26 x86_64 Cygwin

Comment: Looks like it's outputting color codes. Try `ls --color=never` and/or change your terminal type to support color.

Comment: Thank you! That probably is the answer. I can check it on monday.

Answer (score 0):

As AIG suggested, this was due to the color codes used by `ls`. I had `ls` aliased to `ls --color`.